# Oracle SQL Remove Duplicates on 2 of 4 fields

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am using Oracle SQL to extract the data;

I have supply periods for IDs in 2 systems. I have this working with the below code:

```
select distinct b.ID_Code, b.supply_start_date, b.supply_end_date, b.system_id
from (
 select ID_Code, max(supply_start_date) as max_dt 
 from tmp_mmt_sup 
 group by ID_Code) a
inner join tmp_mmt_sup b
on a.ID_Code=b.ID_Code and a.max_dt=b.SUPPLY_START_DATE;
```

However, I have several records that are on the 2 different systems, but have the same start date/end dates. I only want to keep one of them - not bothered which!

So instead of

```
ID_Code    Start        End          System
123        01-04-2018   30-04-2018   ABC
123        01-04-2018   30-04-2018   DEF
```

I only have one of these records.

Many thanks
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care which one to return, then one of aggregate functions (such as `MIN` or `MAX`) does the job. For example:

```
select b.id_code, 
       b.supply_start_date, 
       b.supply_end_date, 
       max(b.system_id) system_id    --> added MAX here ...
from (select id_code, 
             max(supply_start_date) as max_dt 
      from tmp_mmt_sup 
      group by id_code
     ) a
inner join tmp_mmt_sup b 
  on a.id_code = b.id_code and a.max_dt = b.supply_start_date
group by b.id_code,                  --> ... and GROUP BY here
         b.supply_start_date, 
         b.supply_end_date;
```